# Applying CSS to a class within Joomla Module

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I have a Joomla Module.
when I inspect the CSS in firebug, there are many divs in the module.
for example

```
<div class="moudle-class">
<div class="Image-block">
</div>
</div>
```

The Css for image-block:

```
.image-block {
    position: relative;
}
```

This is just a small example, though there are many divs within divs with their own class.

I want to modify the css for class `img-block` for a specific module, not across all modules.

for example:

```
.image-block {
position: relative;
float:left
}
```

If I use a class suffix, that is added to module class and doesn't apply to image-block.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Class_Suffixes#Page_Class_Suffix_.28No_Space.29)!

Comment: @Tijmen - which documentation - you are talking about, Joomla? I have read that well.

Comment: I'm talking about the Joomla documentation. Specifically the page I linked to, which explains exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what it explains - I have written it here. when you are using a module class suffix it applies to that module as a whole. not a class within that module.

Comment: my question is how you modify the class `img-block` and not the `module-class` for a specific module. Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Tijmen comment and the Joomla docs you can add a Page Class Suffix and then use as a target:

```
.myBlogClass .img-block {
  /*your custom css here*/
}
```

Ass far as I can remember modules support [Class Suffix to](https://docs.joomla.org/Module_Class_Suffix) in Joomla if you dont want to use a "whole page" class suffix.

```
.myNewModuleClass .img-block {
  /*your custom css here*/
}
```